# Crystal Reports: How to supress a field based on a Query

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to supress a field in Crystal report based on a query result (true or false). Is there a way to specify the query in a variable and use that variable to create formula for supressing just a field value? Or do you suggest any other mechanism?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@codematrix

I would suggest the following mechanism:

- Create a 'shared' variable within a Formula field in the Report
  Header area (or near the beginning of the report.  Call it:
  @QueryResult (or some other appropriate name) and define it as a
  BooleanVar.
- Create a sub-report and execute the query within the subreport and
  set @QueryResult according based on the outcome.
- Somewhere after the sub-report you can reference @QueryResult in a
  Formula field and leverage it for subsequent logic.

Please let me know if this makes sense.  I've used this technique in Crystal 7 up through XI.

Reference: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.doc.crdesigner/reportdesigner/crconvariablescopecrystalsyntax.htm

Comment: @GlennFerrierLive: Thank you so much. I got the idea. Can you please tell me how to create a query in sub report and assign the return value to my shared Boolean variable. I need to add some conditions in my query. (For ex,  = "Report" etc..)

Comment: Is the query in the sub report dependent on values in the main report (as a right table is dependent on the left in a sql join)?

Comment: Nope. It's completely based on the tables in the sub report. But I need to add some conditions also (For ex, tblTemp.Id = 2 etc..)

Comment: sure. you can put that logic in the Formula Field or add a CASE statement to your SQL.